# Summarise to return the length by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a new column to the data frame below that calculates maximum dry spell length for each month.
This is what my data frame looks like:

```
   day month year  rr spell spell1
     1     1 1981  0   dry      1
     2     1 1981  0   dry      1
     3     1 1981  0   dry      1
     4     1 1981  1.1 dry      0
     5     1 1981  0   dry      1
     6     1 1981  0   dry      1
     7     1 1981  0   dry      1
     8     1 1981  0   dry      1
     9     1 1981  2.7 dry      0
    10     1 1981  0   dry      1
```

This is the output I need:

```
 month year  spell_length
     1 1981      3
     1 1981      4
     1 1981      1
```

this is what I have done so far:

```
group_by(df, year, month, spell1) %>% 
    summarise(spell2 = sum(spell1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

and this is the result:

```
  year month spell1 spell_length
  <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1981     1      1     31
2  1981     2      0      0
3  1981     2      1     27
4  1981     3      0      0
5  1981     3      1     25
6  1981     4      0      0
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(h= T, text="day month year  rr spell spell1
1     1 1981  0   dry      1
2     1 1981  0   dry      1
3     1 1981  0   dry      1
4     1 1981  1.1 dry      0
5     1 1981  0   dry      1
6     1 1981  0   dry      1
7     1 1981  0   dry      1
8     1 1981  0   dry      1
9     1 1981  2.7 dry      0
10     1 1981  0   dry      1")
```

Comment: Could you explain how your output is achieved? For instance what does `rr` mean?

Comment: `rr` means rainfall value, and `spell` == `dry` if `rr` < 1.0, also `spell1` == `1` if `spell` == `dry` else `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to group by 'run-length-id' of 'spell' (`rleid` from `data.table` - creates a new grouping id when the value changes in that column), `filter` out the rows having 'spell1' is 0, get the number of rows with `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    group_by(year, month, grp = rleid(spell1)) %>%
    filter(spell1 ==1) %>%
    summarise(spell_length = n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   year month spell_length
#  <int> <int>        <int>
#1  1981     1            3
#2  1981     1            4
#3  1981     1            1
```

---

Or use `rle` from `base R`

```
rl1 <- rle(df1$spell1)
rl1$lengths[rl1$values > 0]
#[1] 3 4 1
```

NOTE: This solution also works when the 'spell1' values are different

Comment: Thank you akrun. Your suggestions works perfectly. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Using `dplyr` we can create groups at every occurrence of 0 using `cumsum` and sum the number of `spells` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(month, year, group = cumsum(spell1 == 0)) %>%
  summarise(spell_length = sum(spell1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#    month  year spell_length
#   <int> <int>        <int>
#1     1  1981            3
#2     1  1981            4
#3     1  1981            1
```

Comment: This works well as well. I have interchanged `month` and `year` in `group_by` to maintain the original arrangement of the data. Thank you @Ronak Shah.  why the use of `ungroup()` at the end please?.

Comment: @ahmadbello if you don't do `ungroup()` all the calculations you do ahead will be grouped and it might impact the calculations which you might do ahead. So on a safer side it is better to `ungroup` the data.

Answer (score 4):

Using the basic idea from @akrun but without `data.table::rleid()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(year, month, rleid = with(rle(spell1), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 filter(spell1 > 0) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 count(month, year, rleid, name = "spell_length") %>%
 select(-rleid) 

  month  year spell_length
  <int> <int>        <int>
1     1  1981            3
2     1  1981            4
3     1  1981            1
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(year, month, rleid = with(rle(spell1), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 filter(spell1 > 0) %>%
 summarise(spell_length = length(rleid)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using `dplyr::count` :

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, month, year, grp = cumsum(spell1 == 0), zero = spell1==0) %>%
  filter(!zero) %>%
  select(-zero, - grp)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   month  year     n
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1  1981     3
# 2     1  1981     4
# 3     1  1981     1
```

Or in base R :

```
res <- aggregate(day ~  month + year + cumsum(spell1 == 0) + (spell1==0), df, length)
res[!res[[4]],-(3:4)]
#   month year day
# 1     1 1981   3
# 2     1 1981   4
# 3     1 1981   1
```